# How to dynamically convert source folder structure to delta table partition using ADF data flow?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Source (CSV) - In **myfile.csv** I have country column that needs to be created as partition column in target side.

```
/raw/myfolder/myfile.csv
```

Target (Delta)

```
/raw/myfolder/country=<value>/delta_log
-----------------------------/part*.parquet
```

This seems possible using optimize partitions to use key partition type and this needs to be done MANUALLY. However, in my case **I want to pass partition column (in this case country) as a parameter dynamically.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the key column has to be part of the schema **before runtime**, and schema can only be dynamically inferred **at runtime**, I don't think you can do this with partitioning by keys

You can, however, pass the key column in from the executing pipeline and create the folder structure that way, since you can specify the folder as a parameter.

Comment: Yes that can be done to maintain same folder hierarchy. However, this will not update partition column info in delta log. So at the end it is not going to be partition delta table (if one to be created on top of target path)

Comment: You might have to do this in the ARM template then. Are the values only able to be determined at runtime?

Comment: Yes, it is to be determined at runtime only